# VBA Runtime 91 Error While Trying to Web Scrape

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate some web scraping of data through VBA and I consistently receive a

> Runtime error 91 "object variable not set"

on the line

```
For Each htmlele In ieobj.document.getElementById("j_id_jsp_747894496_2").getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

I've included the full code below. I can see that `htmlele` is not declared, but I'm not sure that that may be the issue. All the object libraries necessary have been loaded, so no issue with VBA recognizing the objects, but not sure exactly why it errors.

```
Sub import_ECS()
    Dim courses As Workbook
    Set courses = Excel.Workbooks("CANTRAC Courses")
    Dim ECSws As Worksheet
    Set ECSws = courses.Sheets("ECS")
    Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
    Set ieobj = New InternetExplorerMedium

    Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2

    Dim ECSURL As String
    ECSURL = "https://app.prod.cetars.training.navy.mil/cantrac/pages/rpt_classes_by_cin.html?cin=A-830-0030&p=1"


    ieobj.navigate ECSURL
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")



    For Each htmlele In ieobj.document.getElementById("j_id_jsp_747894496_2").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        With ECSws
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(4).textContent
            .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(7).textContent
            .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(8).textContent
            .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(9).textContent
            .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(10).textContent
        End With
    i = i + 2
    Next htmlele

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to set this `ieobj.document.getElementById("j_id_jsp_747894496_2")` to a variable and have its value not be `Nothing`? (before starting your loop, just to test it)

Comment: I set that `ieobj.document.getElementById("j_id_jsp_747894496_2")` into a variant variable and it's value did come back as `nothing`

Comment: If it's `Nothing` its contents can't be used. That explains the error. Find out why it's `Nothing` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: When you view the source of the page, can you find `j_id_jsp_747894496_2` anywhere? If so, include the entire line of code that has it in your question. (you will have to put 4 spaces before it for it to turn into viewable code here)

Comment: Here it is. This is the html where the ID# is located:
    <form id="j_id_jsp_747894496_2" name="j_id_jsp_747894496_2" method="post" action="/cantrac/pages/rpt_classes_by_cin.html" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">